# Getting SQLSTATE in psql error messages

Tags: postgresql, psql, client, errors

I have the following problem.

```
SELECT * FROM tgvbn();
ERROR:  function tgvbn() does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM tgvbn();
                      ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Since [Appendix A](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/errcodes-appendix.html) of the official documentation only states error_codes and conditional names but not the actual messages, one can only guess that "No function matches..." refers to `42883 / undefined_function`.  I can set `log_error_verbosity = verbose` in `postgresql.conf` - but that will affect the logs, not the messages returned to the client:

> Controls the amount of detail written in the server log for each
>   message that is logged.

Well, I can consult the logs for this piece of information, but is there any means of including it in the error messages?

Comment: This is more a psql problem than a "server configuration" problem. My SQL client does show the SQLSTATE in such a case.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, your comment directed me towards the solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on a_horse_with_no_name's comment, I started searching around `psql` and found the solution:

```
\set VERBOSITY verbose
SELECT * FROM tgvbn();

ERROR:  42883: function vfjkb() does not exist
...
```

Now that goes into `.psqlrc`.  Details and further options can be found in the [psql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-psql.html#AEN81679).

Comment: I quickly scanned through the manual after posting my comment, but I didn't see that one ;) Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like since version 9.2 there is functionality for this:

```
DECLARE
  text_var1 text;
  text_var2 text;
BEGIN
  -- some processing which might cause an exception
  ...
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS text_var1 = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
                          text_var2 = PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL;
END;
```